# Azure DevOps Pipelines gt comparison of integers inconsistent

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to compare a value returned from an API call as a string to the integer 60, to check that it is larger than 60. I'm currently using the following line but noticed this was always evaluating to false.

```
condition: gt(variables['nextCapacity'], '60')
```

I tried testing with proper integers as below and this seems to work as expected.

```
condition: gt(60, 40)
```

I tried them as strings, this seems to typecast correctly and also work as expected, evaluating as true.

```
condition: gt('60', '40')
```

However, when I try the following, I would expect to get true but I get false.

```
condition: gt('219', '5')
```

Is there a proper way to cast strings to integers, or is there a more reliable way to achieve this comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
condition: lt(60, variables['nextCapacity'])
```

According to [gt expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#gt):
**gt Converts right parameter to match type of left parameter.**

The variable values are considered as strings, i.e. your 60 is converter to string and then is compared.